# How to install cinder C++ on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, installation, cinder

I used this command to install cinder on ubuntu 12.04 :

```
git clone -b dev --recursive git://github.com/cinder/Cinder.git cinder_master
```

Now I have a folder cinder_master created with a bunch of folders in it. I know it will sound stupid but how to start cinder or do I need something else to do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you followed the instructions from http://libcinder.org/docs/welcome/GitSetup.html ... According to the site

> "Cinder is free, open-source and available for Mac OS X, iOS and Windows."

So no ubuntu is supported out of the box.

When I look at the source  it has some very deep dependencies to Windows and Mac internals, such as:

```
#if defined( CINDER_MAC )
    #include "cinder/cocoa/CinderCocoa.h"
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import <AppKit/NSPasteboard.h>
    #import <AppKit/NSImage.h>
#elif defined( CINDER_COCOA_TOUCH )
    #include "cinder/cocoa/CinderCocoa.h"
    #include "cinder/cocoa/CinderCocoaTouch.h"
    #import <UIKit/UIPasteboard.h>
#elif defined( CINDER_MSW )
    #include <windows.h>
    #include "cinder/msw/CinderMsw.h"
    #include "cinder/msw/CinderMswGdiPlus.h"
    #include "cinder/Utilities.h"
    #include "cinder/ip/Fill.h"
    #include "cinder/ip/Blend.h"
    #include <set>
#endif
```

so no Linux branch. However you could get "in touch" with cinder developers, ask them if they plan to provide Linux support ... Maybe volunteer yourself for it?

Comment: Which means I can learn it only on a Windows or Mac machine ? How sad ... :( Thank you for answering so fast . Now I can sleep in peace and plan to learn it from my Windows PC :(. Nice offer but I don't think I would be of any help :))

Comment: If Cinder can't be installed on Linux why does this exist - https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/wiki/Cinder-for-Linux-|-Ubuntu-15.X-on-x86_64. I'm having trouble getting it to build but surely its possible.

Comment: It seems a lot of things have changed in recent times so maybe cinder will come to linux ...

Answer (score 3):

This is a good thread to follow for a recent discussion:

https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/next-steps-for-the-linux-fork

The linux-dev-glfw3 branch works, but is outdated at this point as the cinder_master is using GLNext.

Answer (score 1):

As **fritzone** said, there is no current version running on Linux, however there is some development (hopefully) happening.

https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/basicapp-in-linux

And probably for Android as well.